# Event handling inside constructor

Tags: javascript, events, closures, private

I'm really sorry, but i can't figure out why it doesn't work. `printStr()` can access variable only defined in `Foo` constructor, but not in private function, that got triggered on `mousedown` event. Is there any way to access `string` without declaring `printStr` inside `getBotheredByBrendanEich` func?

```
function Foo(elem) {
  elem.on('mousedown', getBotheredByBrendanEich);

  function getBotheredByBrendanEich() {
    var string = 'its just werks!';
    elem.on('mouseup', printStr);
  }

  function printStr() {
    console.log(string);
  }
}

var test = new Foo($('#test'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `string` is a local variable inside of the function `get...()` and is ONLY available inside of that scope.  Local variables are only available within the function they are declared in, which in this case is your `get...()` function

If you want it available in a broader scope so that `printStr()` can use it, then you have to declare it at a higher scope.

You could solve this by using an anonymous function declared in the same scope:

```
function Foo(elem) {
  elem.on('mousedown', getBotheredByBrendanEich);

  function getBotheredByBrendanEich() {
    var str = 'its just werks!';
    elem.on('mouseup', function() {
      console.log(str);
    });
  }
}

var test = new Foo($('#test'));
```

Or, you could pass the argument to the event handler with `.bind()`:

```
function Foo(elem) {
  elem.on('mousedown', getBotheredByBrendanEich);

  function getBotheredByBrendanEich() {
    var string = 'its just werks!';
    elem.on('mouseup', printStr.bind(this, string));
  }

  function printStr(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
  }
}

var test = new Foo($('#test'));
```

Or, you could move the variable to a higher scope so it can be shared:

```
function Foo(elem) {
  elem.on('mousedown', getBotheredByBrendanEich);

  var str = 'its just werks!';

  function getBotheredByBrendanEich() {
    elem.on('mouseup', printStr);
  }

  function printStr() {
    console.log(str);
  }
}

var test = new Foo($('#test'));
```

---

In all cases though, this structure is troublesome because you've adding a new `mouseup` event handler everytime the mousedown event occurs.  This means you will get multiple mouseup handlers after only a couple clicks.  This is rarely ever what you really want to do.

I would suggest this which will not suffer from that problem:

```
function Foo(elem) {
  var str = 'its just werks!';

  elem.on('mousedown', function() {
      // whatever code you want here
  });
  elem.on('mouseup', function() {
      console.log(str);
  });
}

var test = new Foo($('#test'));
```

---

One more comment.  Your code doesn't show any reason to actually use a constructor here.  It appears like you could just implement a normal function call since there is no object instance data.